# Ext.form.ComboBox , Ext.data.ArrayReader , Ext.data.Store not able to render the array properly

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am not able to render the values of array under the drop down , instead it is coming as

`"DocLib1,DocLib2,DocLib3,DocLib4,DocLib5"` in the

Answer (score 0):

ArrayReader suppose to work with format `[[data,data,...],[data,data,...],..]`.